# Recover formatted HDD while mounting the drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-server, forensics, recovery

I had **Windows Server** installed on a **SSD** and a **1TB HDD** with all the photos and files.
I decided to use **Ubuntu Server** instead and i installed it in my **SSD**.
Once installed I looked for my **1TB HDD** but I didn't find it so I followed a tutorial and mounted it.

The problem is that now **I have lost all of my data and I don't know how to recover it**.
How can I recover the data? What tools do you reccomend?

The HDD now has linux file system but the files I need are with windows file system.
So when I use tools like recuva the HDD isn't detected.

I tried easeUS but it's expensive is that the only way?

Comment: If you formatted the drive then data recovery depending on the amount of data you have since written to the device is extremely unlikely

Comment: I haven't written anything since I formatted. I tried with easeUS and I can recover it but it costs like 60$. Is there a free option?

Comment: There are many free data recovery applications.

Comment: Unfortunately all the recovery tools are for Windows. In any case, I suggest to take the disk out of the computer in the meantime to minimize further damage.

Comment: I have already plugged it off, I also have a windows pc where I can plug the HDD and run some software. Could you name some free recovery tools for windows?